# How to fix a low quality glitter texture in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, effects, texture

I'm using Illustrator to make a mockup for flyer. I want to add a glitter effect on heading, but when I apply the grain effect, it becomes very pixelated, doesn't look good.

Here is example:
[image]

what I want is this(this one I created in Figma through scaling a glitter texture):
[image]

Could you help me to understand how to create a good quality glitter texture in Illustrator? I have tried a lot of things, and now the only result I got is save the texture as pdf from Figma and then upload this pdf to Illustrator, but it also doesn't look very good for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you don't use an effect in Illustrator for this, nor use Illustrator to create the texture itself.

Instead, find a good quality high resolution raster image of a nice glitter texture you like. Or alternatively make your own from scratch, [using Photoshop](https://www.patternanddesign.com/how-to-create-glitter-texture-in-photoshop/) or some other raster image editor.

Copy and paste it, or place it in Illustrator, and type some text on top

Select both text and raster image and do *Object > Clipping Mask > Make*

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the effects menu, select "Document Raster Effect Settings," and set the resolution to 300DPI. This should take care of the graininess, though I'm not sure if it will create a convincing glitter texture without some extra processing. You won't get the clumping and highlights like you see in your sample from Figma.

I would recommend generating a large texture graphic and importing it to Illustrator, using the text as a clipping mask on the image. Place the image in illustrator, and then place the text object on top of it. Select both the text and the image, and hit control + 7 (command + 7 on MAC) to create the clip.

[image: Effect > Document Raster Effect Settings...]
[image: Document Raster Effect Settings panel]